# Is there a workaround for evaluating Boolean variables within a Google Data Studio CASE statement?

Tags: boolean, expression, case, looker-studio

I am creating a Google Data Studio report which has a Boolean (True/False) variable in it.  Rather than the report displaying "TRUE" or "FALSE" I would like to display "Yes" (if true) and "-" (if false).  I tried to create a new dimension variable in Data Studio leveraging a CASE statement; however, it apparently does not allow the use of the CASE statement when Boolean variables are in the expression.

I find it odd (actually a bit frustrating) Data Studio can handle a 'IS NULL" scenario and yet is unable to handle a Boolean scenario.

Is there a workaround for my situation which does NOT involve me having to create a new variable within the raw (input to Data Studio) data itself?

Thanks!

Comment: [As of REVISION 1] **Needs details**: Could you provide a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (TO-DO) (and sample data set(s) / Google Sheet (TO-DO)) of the scenario, that shows 1) Input table(s) (~9 rows) (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (TO-DO)) 2) Expected output (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (TO-DO)) 3) An attempt at solving the issue (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (TO-DO))? Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to visualise and pinpoint a suggestion to a specific use case

Answer (score 2):

case when Boolean = TRUE then "yes" else "-" end

This works for me, give it a try!